# How to set default value for an attribute through install script?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, setup-script, create

I have created an attributes using an install script for a custom module. One attribute is a drop-down which only has two options as 'yes','no'. The other attribute is a text field. I need to set default values through this script. I tied the following. But didn't work.

```
$th =  new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();  
$th->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'credit', array(
            'group' => 'Prices',
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Credit rewards',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => 'kkkkkkkk', // this is default value. but is's not setting
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple',
        ) );
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
         /**
         * @var $th Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
         */
        $th =new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $th->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'credit', array(
            'group'                      => 'Prices',
            'type'                       => 'text',
            'backend'                    => '',
            'frontend'                   => '',
            'label'                      => 'Credit rewards',
            'input'                      => 'text',
            'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible'                    => true,
            'required'                   => false,
            'user_defined'               => true,
            'default'                    => 'kkkkkkkk', // this is default value.
            'searchable'                 => false,
            'filterable'                 => true,
            'comparable'                 => false,
            'visible_on_front'           => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing'    => true,
            'unique'                     => false,
            'apply_to'                   => 'simple',
        ));
```

Comment: I want to add a product attribute

Comment: It will add "credit" attribute to product entity

Comment: tested. But it's not setting the default vale in the text box

Comment: you should remove first installed attribute, I also tested and it works perfect

Comment: Yes. I removed all the previous installed scripts and put this one. Attribute is creating. But what I want is to set the default value.

Comment: Are you running exact this script or adding some changes, which version of Magento, if you add default value via admin form it saves correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11195/discussion-between-su123-and-mageuz)

Comment: hi did you solve the problem? By setting the 'default' field the default value appears as default for the attribute in the backend. But the default value is not set for already existing products.

Answer (score 2):

```
     /**
     * @var $th Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
     */
    $th =new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $th->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'credit', array(
        'group'                      => 'Prices',
        'type'                       => 'text',
        'backend'                    => '',
        'frontend'                   => '',
        'label'                      => 'Credit rewards',
        'input'                      => 'text',
        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                    => true,
        'required'                   => false,
        'user_defined'               => true,
        'default'                    => 'kkkkkkkk', // this is default value.
        'searchable'                 => false,
        'filterable'                 => true,
        'comparable'                 => false,
        'visible_on_front'           => true,
        'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing'    => true,
        'unique'                     => false,
        'apply_to'                   => 'simple',
    ));
```